# Change xmlns value of soap root element

Tags: java, soap, xsd, jaxb, saaj

I need to change the xmlns empty string value that is getting generated.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <AirShoppingRQ xmlns=""
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="17.2" >
```

Expected :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <AirShoppingRQ xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="17.2" >
```

Have tried editing packag-info.java as

```
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        xmlns = {
                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsd",
                        namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
                @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsi",
                        namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
        }
)
```

below is the root element :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "AirShoppingRQ")
public class AirShoppingRQ {
}
```

Even though i tried removing it as attribute, but not able to add it again.

```
 SOAPElement x = (SOAPElement) body.getChildElements().next();
        x.removeAttribute("xmlns");
```

Please note : **xmlns should not have any "ns2" or "ns3" prefix** ,as server is not accepting it.

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "AirShoppingRQ", namespace = "http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2")
public class AirShoppingRQ {
}
```

or if you have a schema with that namespace as the targetNamespace I think you can use e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "AirShoppingRQ", namespace = "##default")
public class AirShoppingRQ {
}
```

Comment: It is generating like this after your change <AirShoppingRQ xmlns:ns5="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2"  . with ns5 server is not accepting it